# How to escape character to become a string (ex: \u001 to "\u001")

Tags: c#, qt, encoding, ascii

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { (byte)1 })
// this outputs "\u0001" in the debugger, but the value is a char 

Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { (byte)9 })
// this outputs: "\t" in the debugger, but the value is a char
```

How do I transform this `Char` to its string literal?

`\u0001` -> `"\\u0001"`

`\t` -> `"\\t"`

`Regex.Escape()` seems to work on the `\t` , but not the `\u`

I'm looking to convert a byte array with values `[0, 1, 2, ... 255]`, to parse to a format Qt can read:

> \0\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\xe\xf\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff

... and my above approach is how I figured I'd handle it.

But the following approach:

```
var output = string.Concat(
    byteArray.Select(
        b =>
            b > 128 ?
                $"\\x{b:X2}".ToLower() :
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { b })
                    .Replace("\\u000", "\\x")
    )
);
```

fails because the `.Replace()` never actually does anything.

Comment: The debugger is highlighting that for you. Do you want the escaped form to use in code?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I've tried Regex.Escape() but it just returns the character as-is.

Comment: `Regex.Escape` returns a character escaped *for regular expressions*. If you're actually interested in C# escape sequences, that's a different domain.

Comment: I mean, for the ASCII character set, you can just take the hexadecimal value of the byte, pad it to 4 characters and pop "\\u" in front of it. It's not clear what you want to do (or why). Having that information would better help determine an answer.

Comment: I've edited the main post for context

Comment: How about a `switch` statement with some pattern matching. Use `case` on things like `\t`, `\n` and friends, and then some pattern-matching ranges for other chunks of the Unicode code point space you want to use `\uWXYZ`.

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing :-) I'll forever wonder how to properly escape a character, though, but it seems simply not possible.